# Selecting multiple input parameter in dropdown in JS

Tags: javascript, dropdown

I am trying to create a dropdown list that takes two input parameters (name, IPAddress). I have declared global variable Name and IP to track which name and ip address have been selected. However, the part that I am having a trouble is that it is not recognizing the IP address. Single name can have multiple IP address that I want to recognize both name and IP address when it was selected in dropdown list :(

Any advise on this would be appreciated! Thank you!

```
 //called after name changed
 function selectName(){
   Name = $(#"name :selected").val();
  }

//create dropdown list for name and IPAddress
function createDropList (name, IPAddress){
  $('#name').empty();
  $('#name').append('<option disabled selected value=""> Select Name </option>');
    for (var i=0; i<IPAddress.length; i++) {
        $('#name').append('<option value= "'+name[i]+'" >'+IPAddress[i] + " (IP :"+IPAddress[i] +")" +'</option>');
  }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
$('#name').append('<option value= "'+name[i]+'" >'+
    IPAddress[i] + " (IP :"+IPAddress[i] +")" +'</option>');
```

generates this:

```
<option value= "name" >1.2.3.4 (IP :1.2.3.4)</option>
```

You need:

```
$('#name').append('<option value= "'+name[i]+':'+
    IPAddress[i] + '">(IP :"'+IPAddress[i] +")" +'</option>');
```

to generate:

```
<option value= "name:1.2.3.4">(IP :1.2.3.4)</option>
```

In this way, your value will be the name and IP separated by a colon (:)

To set the global variable "IP" to the value when selected:

```
$('#name').on('change', function() {
    var value= $('#name').val().split(':');
    Name= value[0];
    IP= value[1];
}
```

Comment: I want to save IPAddress to global variable IP as well so that I can pull information from database where that contains particular username and IP Address. How do I have to do in this case..?

Comment: I have updated my answer.  BTW, using global variables is bad- you should try to avoid using globals.

Comment: When I set IP global variable like you told me, I just get results that are based on that IP address. When I do "Name = $(#"name :selected").val();" , my result is just based on username. When I set both, it just not work :( Why can't I set both Name and IP on selected value? I want the results to be both depend on username and ip address :(

Comment: OK, I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: how do I just save username itself?

Comment: I've modified the example again to set two global variables: `IP` and `NAME`

Comment: Above method won't save anything to global variables.. :( Name and IP are still empty :(

Comment: I didn't need  $('#name').on('change', function() { this part to save username and IP!